# How to git-push to a new directory?

Tags: git

I'm keeping a local git repository for a project, but now want to share it with another developer. It will be done by keeping a repository on a network drive that we both have access to.

If I was just starting a project, I'd make a `git --bare init` to the network drive and then create the local repository by pulling from there. But now there is already a local repository. What to do?

Comment: The local repository is also a bare. So you just paste the full path of the repository to another people. Then they call git clone `full path`.

Comment: Another way, you can create a bare repository by a local repository. The command is `git clone --bare fullpath`.

Answer (score 3):

You can do `git clone --bare <location of your local repo>` which will create a bare clone of your repository that you can push and pull from.

http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-clone